# Angular2 datePipe returning formatted date but with an additional month

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

This is my formatter function:

```
public formatDate(date: Date): string {
    var datePipe = new DatePipe();

    if (date) {
        return datePipe.transform(date, 'yMd');
    } else {
        return "--";
    }
};
```

When I use it

```
   let dateFooBar = new Date(2016, 5, 10); //NOtice month 5!!!!
   console.log("Date : " + this.formatDate(dateFooBar)) //output: Date : 6/10/2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behaviour for `Date` class in <strike>Angular 2</strike> **JavaScript**, take a look at this:

```
export class HeroBirthdayComponent {
    birthday = new Date(1988, 3, 15); // April 15, 1988
}
```

You can check official documentation and example I provided [on Angular 2 official website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

You can also check JavaScript `Date` class on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for more details.

Comment: It is normal behaviour for the `Date` class in **JavaScript**, which uses zero-based months by convention (0 = January, 1 = February, etc.).

Comment: @MichaelLiu You are completely right, I edited my answer. Thanks.